# Why Initializing object to null is not dereferenced the object in java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working with an application where I have implemented  observer pattern which will set the slider value on change in model.
I have a button called clear which will  clear the window and set the  observer to null before removing the listener .So after this i did the memory mapping with profiler .But I was  scared  to find that the object is still there. 
In my 2nd exp Before making the observer null I first remove all the listener then i make it null and i found from profiler that the object is now collected by garbage collector.
Below i provide the snipnet of this code .Any light on this will be appreciated .

```
  controls = new Createcontrols();
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        controlbox = controls.creatControls();
        vbox.getChildren().add(controlbox);
        final Button clear = new Button("clear");
        vbox.getChildren().add(clear);
        EventHandler deletehnadler=     new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vbox.getChildren().clear();
                // controls.dispose();
                controls=null;                   
            }      
          };
```

Createcontrol class:

```
package com.nxp.designpattern.observer;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Createcontrols implements ObserverInterface {

    private Slider slider;
    private static int counter;
    private Subject m_subject;
    private Button next_button;
    private Button previous_buttButton;
    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> nexteventhandler;
    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> prevhandler;

    public Createcontrols() {
        m_subject = new Subject();
        ObserverImpl.getObserverImpl().addListener(this);

    }

    public VBox creatControls() {
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        next_button = new Button("next");
        previous_buttButton = new Button("Previous");

        slider = new Slider();
        vbox.getChildren().add(next_button);
        vbox.getChildren().add(previous_buttButton);
        vbox.getChildren().add(slider);
        nexteventhandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter += 10;
                m_subject.setValue(counter);
            }
        };
        next_button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, nexteventhandler);
        prevhandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter -= 10;
                m_subject.setValue(counter);
            }
        };
        previous_buttButton.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, prevhandler);
        return vbox;
    }

    @Override
    public void changeinvalue(int value) {
        slider.setValue(value);

    }

    void dispose() {
        next_button.removeEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, nexteventhandler);
        // nexteventhandler=null;
        previous_buttButton.removeEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, prevhandler);
        // prevhandler=null;
        ObserverImpl.getObserverImpl().removeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting an object reference to null isn't guaranteed to immediately invoke the garbage collector.

Comment: @EJP yes i knew it.Even after calling the dispose for removing listener also it is not removing the object .But  In profiler i have some thing called force garbage collection when I am invoking that one in my second case my memory is  coming back to normal but in my 1st case  the object is still there

Comment: Please donot downvote and close .If you  r not clear about the question then please leave a comment

Comment: I've left a comment. You expectations are misplaced. Yo can force Gc to occur via your tool, but not by just setting a reference to null.

Comment: @ejp. yes ..But After forcing through the tool also why it is not releasing memory in my 1st case when I am not disposing the listener

Comment: I already mentioned please do not downvote .I am a newbie to this field.Please comment if you have any doubt.

Comment: If the profiler tells you that the object is still there it will also tell you why it’s still there.

Comment: Because there is still a reference to it, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In my 2nd exp Before making the observer null I first remove all the listener then i make it null"
This is the problem/solution. The variable is just a pointer, setting it to null doesn't do anything to the actual object and the listener still has a reference so it'll never be garbage collected. You have to remove all references.